# How To Respawn A Prefab After 5 Second's?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to spawn a prefab after I destroy the object and only when the object is destroyed.

```
#pragma strict

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        var ray : Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        var hit : RaycastHit;
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit)) {
           if (hit.collider.tag == "destroyable") {
               Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the Prefab in a variable to set on unity editor:

```
var objectToSpawn : GameObject;
```

Before the Spawn code you can use:

```
yield WaitForSeconds (5);
```

Your code would look something like this:

Javascript

```
#pragma strict

var objectToSpawn : GameObject;

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
    var ray : Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        var hit : RaycastHit;
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit)) {
           if (hit.collider.tag == "destroyable") {
               var oldTransform = hit.collider.gameObject.transform;
               Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
               StartCoroutine(SpawnAfter5Seconds(oldTransform));
            }
         }
    }
}

function SpawnAfter5Seconds(oldTransform:Transform)
{
       yield WaitForSeconds (5);
       var newObject = Instantiate (objectToSpawn , oldTransform.position, oldTransform.rotation);
}
```

Comment: I get a error of "Script error (Destroy): Update() can not be a coroutine." What do I do? Thank's for the help aswell.

Comment: I've updated the answer with correct use of yield, I hope that works. You have to use Coroutine so the game won't freeze.

Comment: Thank's again but now i've got the error "Assets/Scripts/Destroy.js(18,43): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end."

Comment: Fixed, it was syntax, sorry, try again.

Comment: I got it to at least 1 error "Assets/Scripts/Destroy.js(18,10): BCE0044: expecting (, found 'SpawnAfter5Seconds'"

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I was not able to test the code at moment, in that line there is one ')' more befores ';'. Updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59071/discussion-between-maikonfarias-and-theevil-potato).

Comment: Thank's! It didn't get any errors except one (Transform) 'MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
UnityEngine.Transform.get_position () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/aeedb04a1292f85a/artifacts/EditorGenerated/UnityEngineTransform.cs:28)'

Comment: Well, this would require more details about the code you are doing, it seems like the object itself was destroyed before it could be executed (oldTransform), I recommend you to check http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/240595/missingreferenceexception-the-object-of-type-trans.html